# How to display Vim confirmation prompts in French but error messages in English

Tags: error

Is there a way to make Vim display confirmation prompts in French but error messages in English?

- I have gotten very used to responding to the French confirmation prompts. A change to English would cause some disorientation because the rest of my computer is in French.
- I would like the error messages to be in English because it is easier to search the error messages online.
- The rest of Vim can be in either English or French. I do not have a preference either way.

Comment: Are you aware that when you get an error, you can do `:help E###`? (I too have vim in French, but the translations are usually straightforward, and the help + debugging is usually enough to get there). Another option: when you get an error, temporarily switch to English and re-do the thing that gave you the error; then back to French

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You have accurately described what I already do. I just want to know if there is an easy way to copy the actual error message in English without `:help` or reproducing the error.